# Spatie Media, создание записи в таблице без перемещения

Tags: php, laravel

Использую модуль `Spatie laravel-medialibrary` для сохранения изображений.
Чтобы сохранить изображение в таблице `media`, нужно вызвать метод `toMediaCollection()` примерно так:

```
$item->addMedia()->toMediaCollection();
```

в результате файл поместится в папку по умолчанию.
Но выбор и сохранение изображения происходит из существующего файла, которые изначально выводятся с помощью `File`

```
$files = collect(File::allFiles(public_path('/images')) );
...
return view('view', ['images' => $files]);
```

они уже находятся в папке, и нужно при выборе и сохранении не перемещать уже существующие изображения, а нужно сделать только запись в таблице `media` о выбранном изображении.
Это нужно из-за того, что изображения могут лежать в подпапках, и в результате нового сохранения изображение переместится в папку, назначенную по умолчанию, а нужно чтобы изображение осталось в своей папке.
Можно ли такое сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда столкнулся с тем, что надо просто добавить запись в Media, возникло 2 решения:

1. Через модель `Media::find(*id*)->replicate()`; Меняешь какие надо свойства и делаешь `->save()`. Но этот способ меня не устроил, ибо очень медленно выполнялся.
2. Второй способ через `$attrs = Media::find(*id*)->getAttributes()`, затем так же меняешь, что надо и делаешь `DB::table('media')->insert($attrs)`. Этот способ работает мгновенно.

При этом `path` указываешь туда где лежит уже файл

Comment: `$attrs = Media::find(*id*)->getAttributes()` это ведь подразумевает, что запись об изображении уже есть в таблице, а изначально записей нет в таблице, и изображения выбираются  с помощью `File`

Comment: Тогда можно вручную набрать массив со значениями для таблицы. Я это тоже проходил. К сожалению я не нашел в spatie встроенного способа без перемещения копировать